# Vuetify changes <vs-button> text color

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

1. *Summarize the problem*

After install `vuetify` the text color from my `<vs-button>` changes from white to black. I can't change the color even with a change in the vuetify theme.
I also made a custom `postcss-filter-rule` in my `vue.config.js` file:

2. *Describe what you’ve tried*

To return to having the color white in all the buttons

3. *Some code*

```
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
    const filterRules = require('postcss-filter-rules')
    
    module.exports = {
      publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL,
    
      devServer: {
        // port: process.env.VUE_APP_PORT,
        https: false,
        hotOnly: false,
      },
    
      configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
              PACKAGE_JSON: '"' + escape(JSON.stringify(require('./package.json'))) + '"'
            }
          })
        ]
      },
      css: {
        loaderOptions: {
          postcss: {
            plugins: [
              filterRules({
                filter: (selector) => {
                  const re = new RegExp(/^(select|vs-button)(\W|$)/, 'i')
                  const exception  = '.vue-global'
                  return !re.test(selector) || selector.includes(exception)
                },
                keepAtRules: true
              }),
              autoprefixer
            ]
          }
        }
      },
    
      transpileDependencies: [
        'vuetify'
      ]
    };
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is white text, you might achieve it by adding `dark` prop to the `v-btn`s.